# Refactoring FastAPI application: Best practices for handling overlapping parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, pydantic

I am working on a **Python** application. It is an **FastAPI** based API and it's main purpose is to provide calculations controlled by received **query parameters**. The project has grown a lot and the number of available API parameters is around 150. I wanted to do some refactoring and ended up with a dilema "how to do things in a better way".

I am using `Python 3.10`, pydantic `2.5.0` and FastAPI `0.104.0`

### Detailed description

All received parameters are stored inside a **dataclass class**. This class is passed to all functions that require to read any parameter. I was unable to split this large class into several smaller ones, because the nature of parameters often overlaps.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
...

@dataclass
class GenChart:
    """
    The following model defines all arguments that are accepted by generate_charts
    """
    sid: int = 1
    time: str = "1m"
    market: str = None
    ...

@app.get('/generate')
async def generate(config_object: GenChart = Depends()):
    response = generate(config_object=config_object)

    return response
```

I am also **adding** some new arguments to the class in the code so flexibility of **dataclass** suits my needs. The total number of arguments can raise up to 200.

```py
def generate(config_object: GenChart):
    # Add new arguments (example)
    config_object.foo = "boo"
```

I wanted to use **Pydantic BaseModel**, however since it is not mutable, it will be necessary to define all arguments on init. This will expose those arguments inside docs and might cause some confusion while reading them after while.

[image: config object passing schema]

### Question

- Is this the right pythonic way?
- What and how can I improve my code architecture?
- Should I rather use Basemodel with (*somehow*) hidden arguments from the API docs?

#### Additional Q&A

- Q: Why there are so many arguments?

  - A: The application serves as a "backtester". It allows to test multiple settings and variables and their combinations. It is an internal tool used by "trained users".

---

*Please excuse me if the question is not clear, I have been working on this topic for a week and it is very difficult to formulate it simply. I do my best to modify the question so that it is as clear as possible. At the same time, I would be glad to be referred to any resources from which I can gain and learn something.*

Comment: "The total number of arguments can raise up to 200." ... Why? Presumably some of those are related to one another (and not to anything else) so it sounds like you'd want an object that is composed of other sub-objects containing that related data.

Comment: @AKX is this bad? I need to think a bit and the main reason is that some particular configuration requires additional values to work properly (so they are populated only if this config is used). But based on your answer (thanks for that), you suggest creating a nested object that holds this configuration and can be empty if not used?

Comment: 200 arguments sounds untenable to reason about or test. (You do have tests, right?) Anyway, yeah, the "sub-container" would be non-present (`None`), yeah, is what I'm envisioning.

Comment: No, code is not covered by tests. I am using "consistency tests", that are testing the calculation outputs. I have left the nested classes model because I often got lost in which class the values are nested in. :D So I have switched to "flat" model and I am always calling the single one object that always contains everything I need.

Comment: (I'm not going to make excuses for not using tests, I just don't know how. My main focus is not programming, but I'm trying to gradually educate myself.)